# how do i remove rows which having same values in sales column on the basis of customerid, date, sales but sign were different

Tags: r

[Ecommerce data][1]

sales column has same value but sign were different like 12344, -12344
as customer has place the order but at the same day or some other day they have cancelled the order. so, wanted to drop the rows which has postive sign value bcz transaction is not been made.

1. filter sales on basis of stockcode, customerid
2. filter sales on basis of stockcode, customerid and date
   filter and remove only positive value bcz after this i can remove all negative values together.

```
> dput(Ecommerce[1:10, ])
structure(list(Invoiceno = c(540815,540815,540818,541220,C545033,545320,C550456,550461,C551685,551697),
Stockcode = c(85123A,21108,48185,22838,22838,21108,21108,POST,POST),
CustomerID = c(15749,15749,15749,14156,14156,14156,15749,15749,16029,16029),
Sales = c(4921.5,6539.4,4522.5,1224,-1224,1224,-65439,65439,-8142.5,8142.5),
Date=c(1/11/2011,1/11/2011,1/11/2011,1/14/2011,2/25/2011,3/1/2011,4/18/2011,4/18/2011,5/3/2011,5/3/2011)), .Names = c("Invoiceno","Stockcode","CustomerID","Sales","Date"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please, provide e reproducible example of the dataset and output desired

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure without a reproducible example, I think this should do what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
Rdata %>%
  filter(sign(Sales) <= 0)
```

Comment: i  have already shared screenshot of data. is the data is not visible on screen?

Comment: I can't copy it into my own R session to try out. Also, in your screenshot, everything in `Sales` is positive, so it's not obvious whether I understood your question. Things would be more clear if you provide a minimal example input that we can copy-paste in R, and the output that you expect.